# Enable an interface in the background

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to know how to put an interface where there are buttons and links in the background, in disabled mode, then it is reactivated after user authentication?

That is to say, when the user authenticates, the page in the background is active .

I use JSF and PrimeFaces.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question..

Comment: I believe the OP overgeneralized the term "interface" from "user interface component", or more precisely "the HTML representation of the JSF component", and hereby thus making the question completely confusing when asked in Java context instead of in HTML/webdev context. I've removed the `[java]` tag.

Comment: @BalusC Your guess is fully legitimate, but without clarification from OP all our attempts would be like chasing a phantom, though the general context is somehow clear, but all 'what exactly' questions are left unexplained.

Comment: how can I move from page to another page by clicking a button and the second page will be in popup. Think you

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have effect like on this demo ?

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/confirmDialog.jsf

That's called overlay, and you can create it in primefaces, or in jquery, but that demo should do the work.

You need to know that when you create such overlay someone might open firebug and just remove overlay element and operate on site content.

Comment: how can I move from  page to another page by clicking a button and
    the second page will be in popup.
Think you

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `disabled` attribute of a JSF command/input component. It accepts a boolean expression.

E.g., assuming you're using container managed authentication to login (and thus, the logged-in user is available via `#{request.remoteUser}` in the view):

```html
<h:commandButton ... disabled="#{not empty request.remoteUser}">
```

As you're using PrimeFaces, an alternative would be to use its `<p:blockUI>` component. See also [its showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/blockUI.jsf) for a concrete example.

Comment: how can I move from page to another page by clicking a button and the second page will be in popup. Think you